# "Unable to restore your chats from this backup. Do you want to restore your chats from an older backup?" WhatsApp message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore, google-backup

I tried all day to move my WhatsApp from one phone to another. I had everything backed up, but when I verified on the new phone, I realised that I forgot the password and the encryption key to restore from Google Drive, but it was too late to change them because I was already logged off the old phone.

So I verified again on my old phone, but the chats were already lost. So I wanted to restore chats on the old phone with local backup, reset password, and then back up on Google Drive and do everything on the new phone, but I get this error when I try to do the restoring:

> Unable to restore your chats from this backup. Do you want to restore your chats from an older backup?

Can somebody help me fix this issue?